# Netgear router slows down after few weeks of activity

Tags: router, memory, speed

I've a Netgear WNDR4500v3 I use to route all the traffic of my home (2 rMBP, 1 iMac, 2 PS4, 1 iPhone, 1 HTC, 1 Epson Printer, 1 Philips TV and 1 Chromecast).

I used to live in an area where the max broadband was about 5 mbit/s and it never had a problem with it.

Recently I moved to an area where I have a 50 mbit/s connection and the problems started:

After few weeks the internet connection suddenly slows down and when I login into the router admin page the panel isn't responsive as it should be.
Once I reboot the router, everything starts working normally again for the next ~2 weeks.

My router is connected to a ZTE modem/router that works just as modem (I have disabled every feature of it), this is the same configuration I had in my previous home (I had a Vodafone Station 2 with everything disabled).

I looked for custom firmwares but seems like the v3 is not supported by neither of them.

Ideas to fix the problem?

Comment: As a general rule, domestic routers have brains the size of peanuts. I'd say you're doing well to go several weeks between reboots. In fact I'd call it 'better than expected behaviour'.

Comment: Yea the problem is that there's not an auto-restart rule in the firmware and I'd like to add domotic stuff soon, this could be a problem :(

Comment: Anecdotally, I only fixed my router's 'peanut' issue by replacing it with a corporate device. Now I reboot it for firmware updates & nothing else. Weeks/months.

Comment: Can you suggest some good brand?

Comment: I use Sophos UTM - it's free for 50 seats , just BYO computer & 2 NICs [but you cannot get support like paying customers, you need to be able to figure it out yourself from the rather comprehensive documentation].